# Boost mpl transformed sequence "real" type

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-mpl

See the following code from the boost mpl transform documentation:

```
typedef vector<char,short,int,long,float,double> types;
typedef vector<char*,short*,int*,long*,float*,double*> pointers;
typedef transform< types,boost::add_pointer<_1> >::type result;
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(( equal<result,pointers>::value ));
```

I want to understand the type system of `boost::mpl` and "how it actually works".
As I understand `mpl::equal` just compares the elements of the following two sequences and not the whole sequence types themselves.
I do not understand why the following fails:

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(( std::is_same<result,pointers>::value )); //< assert fails
```

Why is the result type not 100% identical to the "pointers" type?
I assume that is somehow because mpl is performing the transformation lazy or the result is just a sequence and not a vector any more?
Is it possible to somehow force mpl to do not being lazy any more and get the 100% identical type (I could write a transform function myself with this result, but i want to know how to do it in mpl)?

I tried already some things like e.g. inserting the result in a new vector but without success:

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(( std::is_same<
  mpl::insert_range< mpl::vector<>, mpl::begin<mpl::vector<> >::type,
  result >::type, pointers >::value )); //< assert fails too
```

Also, i tried using a back_insert in the transformation function, which fails too:

```
typedef transform< types,boost::add_pointer<_1>,
  mpl::back_inserter< mpl::vector< > > >::type result_new;
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(( std::is_same<result_new,pointers>::value )); //< fails...
```

Reading the "documentation" did not help me.
So again, is it possible to get the 100% identical type with mpl transform (or any other transforming sequence functions)? And what is the result of the type

```
result
```

"in reality" when it not is_same with pointers?

Comment: I'm guessing that's `boost::mpl::vector` and not `std::vector`? Be careful with the `using` directive, or you might have clashes or in worst case code that's hard to follow and maintain.

Comment: http://liveworkspace.org/code/3l8O9K$0

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thx for pointing that out, it is about `boost::mpl::vector` (the code is from the tutorial and i did not want to modify it). Note that I use the alias `namespace mpl = boost::mpl;` in the rest of the code.

Comment: @llonesmiz Thanks a lot for your code, that really helps in _debugging_ the usage of boost::mpl! So the original type is `boost::mpl::vector` vs the transformated nested types `boost::mpl::v_item`. Still i wonder whether i could convert the v_time's back to mpl::vector. At least i could write my own conversion function now...

Comment: @llonesmiz After switching from g++ to intel compiler at your code paste, *all* result types changed to `boost::mpl::vector6<char*, short*, int*, long*, float*, double*>` which is_same to the `pointers` type (just use `mpl::vector6<>` instead of `mpl::vector<>`) : ). So actually the type gets converted back to vector6<> in that case, which makes it same to the handwritten pointers type. Some thoughts: In the general case (without using variadic types from c++11) the back conversion is not possible as there is always an maximum number N for vectorN<> and a conversion has extra compile costs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks again to @llonesmiz for the code to pretty print the types using typeid(), which helped to understand whats happening.

So it seems the real result type depends on the compiler (probably boost #ifdefs), intel compiler and visual studio convert it back to std::vectorN<> where the maximum N is a predefined number in boost (so it does not work when N is too large).
For g++ a mangled type is generated (even 2 different types from my transform calls).

So i guess checking the type via mpl::equal is fine (check the elements of the ranges).
If all types should be "really" equivalent (std::is_same holds) i guess you need to convert the result manually to a variadic template class std::tuple.

See http://liveworkspace.org/code/3l8O9K$16 [Code Sample](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3l8O9K%2416)

or in short:

```
template < class T, class R >
struct ToStdTuple;

template < class... TTypes, class X >
struct ToStdTuple< std::tuple< TTypes... >, X >
{
  typedef std::tuple< TTypes..., X > type;
};
```

and then

```
// typedef mpl::vector<char,short,int,long,float,double> types;
// typedef mpl::transform< types,boost::add_pointer<mpl::_1> >::type result;

typedef mpl::fold< result, std::tuple<>,
  ToStdTuple< mpl::_1, mpl::_2 > >::type result_normalized;
```

resulting in

```
std::tuple<char*, short*, int*, long*, float*, double*>
```

for all transformation calls

Comment: Very clean solution for converting any `boost::mpl` sequence to a `std::tuple`. **+1**

Comment: This is actually a perfect solution for converting any `boost::mpl` sequence to a specific sequence type... like `boost::python::bases`, which was my goal. Unfortunately, VS2010, which I am using, doesn't support variadic templates, but I've been able to work around this via `Boost.Preprocessor`.